# How to detect double-keyboard with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, events, reactiveui

how to detect double-key board (like double key-Enter) With ReactiveUI

Comment: You mean rapid repetition of the same key (ie. kk) or pressing and keeping on hold (ie Ctrl + C)?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
doubleEnter = someWindow.Events().KeyUp
    .Where(x => x.EventArgs.Key == Key.Enter)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(650), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1);
```